# Django admin. Hide field on change select field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have model:

```
class CategoryField(models.Model):
    selectfield = models.IntegerField(choices=SELECT_FIELD_CHOICES, default=1)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Required?')
```

In admin page I have `selectField` with choices: "value1", "value2", "value3", ...
When I select "value2" I need to show `verified` field. How can I do it?

Comment: You can do in by [overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to add some JavaScript in order to show or hide the field. jQuery 1.9.1 is [available in Django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery) already via the `django.jQuery` object.

The simplest way to add this JavaScript is to add a [Media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/media/) meta class to your model form and add the form to the `ModelAdmin`:

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

class CategoryFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    . . .

    class Media:
        js = ('category-field-admin.js',)


# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

from your_app.forms import CategoryFieldForm
from your_app.models import CategoryField


class CategoryFieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CategoryFieldForm


admin.site.register(CategoryField, CategoryFieldAdmin)


# category-field-admin.js

// pseudo code - change as needed

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var selectField = $('#id_selectField'),
            verified = $('#id_verified');

        function toggleVerified(value) {
            value == 'value2' ? verified.show() : verified.hide();
        }

        // show/hide on load based on pervious value of selectField
        toggleVerified(selectField.val());

        // show/hide on change
        selectField.change(function() {
            toggleVerified($(this).val());
        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```